# How did Shipwreck Cove come to be?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

I was recently rewatching *Pirates of the Caribbean: At Worlds End*, where the fourth Brethren Court convenes at location [aptly] called, Shipwreck Cove.

[image: shipwreck cove]

**Is there any backstory as to how this location, which literally consists of the wrecks of ships, came to be?**

**Secondary Questions to better explain my meaning:**
Are the ships naturally situated, are/were there architects, or was any magic used to make this place usable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no in-universe description of the Cove's history, but we do get this snippet in the [press-kit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100821040553/http://adisney.go.com/disneypictures/pirates/atworldsend/downloads/prodnotes/potc3_productionnotes.pdf) that was released in advance of the film. In short it would appear that pirates who've passed their sell-by dates can retire to the island. When they do so, they shove their (now unneeded) ships into the Shipwreck Cove.

> The last of the fabulous sets built on Disney’s Stage 2 for the “Pirates” trilogy was Shipwreck Cove, where the raucous and divisive Brethren Court of Pirate Lords meets to make a last plan of action against the onslaughts of Beckett and the East India Trading Company armada. **“Shipwreck Cove was conceived by Gore as kind of a retirement home for old pirates, comprised of the wrecked hulls of various ships hidden in a volcano,”** notes Heinrichs. “The Brethren Court meet in one of those hulls, and outside of the structure we’ve extended the set with a 300-foot-long painted backing which has been beautifully 
>   designed and painted in the good, old-fashioned Hollywood tradition.”
>
> The Brethren Court does have some foundation in history, note the screenwriters. “There was a loose confederation of pirates called the Brethren of the Coast,” says Ted Elliott. “And it’s just such a fun idea to have a whole bunch of pirates sitting around trying to come to decisions. Captain Sao Feng has a line of dialogue in which he says that pirates are either captain or crew, and nine captains charting a course is eight captains too many. We also wanted to get more international in flavor, so the Pirate Lords are from all over the world.”